# How addresses are encoded in a Macronix MX35LF1GE4AB Nand flash memory chip?

Tags: nand-flash

I read the documentation for the Macronix MX35LF1GE4AB flash memory chip. And I attempt to implement a script that dumps its contents to a file. So I was reading the chip's documentation https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/d3cc88a78401b520b99e5db36139faaa06978868/1380031917002306mx35lf1ge4ab203v201gb20v1.5.pdf

A major problem that I need to solve is to find out how data are addressed inside the chip. As I see on page 10 there are 1024 blocks containing 63 pages of 2111 bytes.

But once I will issue the 13h command to the chip how I should place the address? Should be in a form:

> ^block^^page^^byte^

Or it sdhould be represented in a different form?

Also, what are wrap addresses in this particular chip? I have the 1Gb variant.

Answer (score 0):

Try page 16 of the data sheet: -

[image]

The address (MSb first) gets clocked in on the 8th clock rising edge.

Comment: Ok but I cannot comperhend what form is an address with iun a meaning of what should I provide as address to my code how I can formulate a data address.